# React component wont display the return of a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, render

I have a component that is supposed to display a "cards" containing information saved in an array in state. I get this information from a JSON file and save it into my array in a "componentDidMount". I then made a function called "displayFood" before the return of my render function, which I then use in my render functions return. The problem is that when I run the code no cards are being displayed.

```
import React from 'react'
import "./style.scss";
import FoodData from "./foodData.json";

class Food extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            foodData: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        FoodData.map((foodItem,index) => {
            var foodTemp = {
                id: index,
                name: foodItem.name,
                pic: foodItem.pic,
                serving: foodItem.serving,
                calories: foodItem.calories,
                sugar: foodItem.sugar,
                protien: foodItem.protien
            }
            this.setState((prevState) => {
                prevState.foodData.push(foodTemp)
            })
        })
    }

  render() {

    const displayFood = () => {
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < this.state.foodData.length; i++){
            return(
                <div className="food-card">
                    <img src={require(`${this.state.foodData[i].pic}`)}/>
                    <ul>
                        <li>{this.state.foodData[i].name}</li>
                        <li>Serving: {this.state.foodData[i].serving}</li>
                        <li>Calories: {this.state.foodData[i].calories}</li>
                        <li>Sugar: {this.state.foodData[i].sugar}</li>
                        <li>Protien: {this.state.foodData[i].protien}</li>
                    </ul>
                    <button name={this.state.foodData[i].name}>Add</button>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

      return(
        <div>
            <div className="food-container">
            {
                displayFood()       
            }
            </div>
        </div>
      )
  }
}

export default Food;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I am not sure your `setState` in`componentDidMount` work. If you don't want to return a new array, you shouldn't use `map`, use `forEach` instead. And you're mutating directly the state, which not recommended. The function should like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
  // Build a new array of object from FoodData
  const newFoodData = 
        FoodData.map(({name, pic, serving, calories, sugar, protien }, index) => 
                     ({ id: index, name, pic, serving, calories, sugar, protien }))
  // Assign the new object to state
  this.setState({ foodData: newFoodData })
}
```

Second, `return` in `for` loop will return the first item only. You should create an array then push item through the loop instead of return

```
const displayFood = () => {
    let cards = [] // Crate an array
    for(let i = 0; i < this.state.foodData.length; i++){
        cards.push( // push item to array through the loop
            <div className="food-card">
                <img src={require(`${this.state.foodData[i].pic}`)}/>
                <ul>
                    <li>{this.state.foodData[i].name}</li>
                    <li>Serving: {this.state.foodData[i].serving}</li>
                    <li>Calories: {this.state.foodData[i].calories}</li>
                    <li>Sugar: {this.state.foodData[i].sugar}</li>
                    <li>Protien: {this.state.foodData[i].protien}</li>
                </ul>
                <button name={this.state.foodData[i].name}>Add</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
  return cards  // Return the array
}
```

And I recommend you to move the `displayFood` outside the `render()` function. Because when other things cause re-render but not the `this.state.foodData` change, the component have to re-build the `displayFood()`. That's wasted.

Comment: Dam bird you nailed it on the head. I implemented your suggestions along with changing the "DidMount" to "WillMount" and it works great. I wish I had more stackoverflow reputation to give you a visible upvote. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome!  Actually, you should put it in `componentDidMount`, just add handle the empty fooData in the render() function. i.e. `if(!this.state.dataFood.length) return <h1>Loading...</h1>`. Because, in real App, the data will not come from JSON file but from API, `componentWillMount` cannot help you a that time. And from version 17, 'componentWillMount' will be deprecated https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Comment: Great to know and will do. I heard about the deprecation of "compnentWillMount" but had not looked into it yet. You seem very knowledgeable on React.

Answer (score 0):

According to the lifecycle, the `render` method is actually already called before `componentDidMount`. Hence, by the time it is rendered, the data is still empty. Why not move data initialization in `componentWillMount`?

Comment: Thanks justelouise I went ahead and changed the "DidMount" to "WillMount" and now it displays the first object in the array correctly. Hopefully I can troubleshoot why the for loop is only giving me one result. (i tried to up vote you but because I have no reputation on this site it wont show)

Answer (score 0):

try to change the previous state... you used directly the data on state, it not changes the state root:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    foodData: [ ...foodData, foodTemp ],
}))
```

Comment: Thanks I made the changes and get the same result of the program only displaying the first item in the Array of state

Answer (score 0):

```
class Hello extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      foodData: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const  { foodData } = this.state;

    foodData.push({
        id: 0,
      name: 'beans',
      pic: 'picurl',
      serving: '2',
      calories: '100',
      sugar: '30',
      protien: '10'
    });

    this.setState({ foodData });

  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <div className="food-container">
        {
          this.state.foodData.map((item,key) => {
            return <div className="food-card">
              {`${item.pic}`}
              <ul>
                <li>{item.name}</li>
                <li>Serving: {item.serving}</li>
                <li>Calories: {item.calories}</li>
                <li>Sugar: {item.sugar}</li>
                <li>Protien: {item.protien}</li>
              </ul>
              <button name={item.name}>Add</button>
            </div>
          })     
        }
      </div>

    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

make sure that your foodData is loaded correctly on 'componentDidMount()'

https://jsfiddle.net/leolima/L7c418kp/13/

Comment: Thanks for the responce Leo. It does look like that would also work but I have already got a solid answer from Bird. Thanks for helping out though.